# Handling url parts in a api returned json format

Tags: python

***  I have updated code at the bottom.

I have a json object I'm working with and it's coming from Azure analytics for an application we build.  I'm trying to figure hot to parse the Url that comes back with just the limits and location keys data in separate columns.  The code I'm using is listed here:  (keys are take out as well as url because of api keys and tokens)

```
import request
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from furl import furl
import json

d1 = '<This is where I have the rule for the API>'

querystring = {"timespan":"P7D") #get's last 7 days
headers = { Stuff in here for headers }

response = requests.request("GET", d1, headers=headers, parms=querystring)

data = json.loads(response.text)

#then I clean up the stuff in the dataframe
for stuff in data(['value'])
    del stuff['count'].....(just a list of all the non needed fields in the json script)

newstuff = json.dumps(data, indent=2, sort_keys=True
data2 = json.loads(newstuff)
```

ok now here is the part I am having problems with, I want to pull out 3 columns of data from each row. the ['request']['url'], ['timestamp'], ['user']['id']

I'm pretty sure I need to do a for loop so I'm doing the following to get the pieces out.

```
for x in data2['value']:
    time = x['timestamp']
    user = x['user']['id']
    url = furl(x['request']['url'])
    limit = url.args['limit']
    location = url.args['location']
```

What's happening is when I try this i'm getting limit does not exist for every url.  I think I have to do a if else statement but not sure how to formulate this.  I need to get everything into a dataframe so I can parse it out into a cursor.execute statement which I know how to do.

What's needed.
1.  Get the information in the for loop into a dataframe 
2.  take the url and if the url does not have a Limit or a Location then make it none else put limit in a column and same for location in a column by itself.

Dataframe would look like this
    timestamp     user          limit    location
    2018-01-01    bob@home.com     null
    2018-01-01    bill@home.com  null    
    2018-01-01    same@home.com  null    null
    2018-01-02    bob@home.com

here is the information on [furl](https://github.com/gruns/furl/)

here is some sample json to test with:

```
   {
    "value": [{
            "request": {
                "url": "https://website/testing"
            },
            "timestamp": "2018-09-23T18:32:58.153z",
            "user": {
                "id": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "request": {
                "url": "https://website/testing/limit?location=31737863-c431-e6611-9420-90b11c44c42f"
            },
            "timestamp": "2018-09-23T18:32:58.153z",
            "user": {
                "id": "steve@home.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "request": {
                "url": "https://website/testing/dealanalyzer?limit=57bd5872-3f45-42cf-bc32-72ec21c3b989&location=31737863-c431-e611-9420-90b11c44c42f"
            },
            "timestamp": "2018-09-23T18:32:58.153z",
            "user": {
                "id": "tom@home.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}




import requests
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


d1 = "https://nowebsite/v1/apps/11111111-2222-2222-2222-33333333333333/events/requests"

querystring = {"timespan":"P7D"}

headers = {
    'x-api-key': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", d1, headers=headers, params=querystring)

data = json.loads(response.text)

# delete crap out of API GET Request
for stuff in data['value']:
    del stuff['count']
    del stuff['customDimensions']
    del stuff['operation']
    del stuff['session']
    del stuff['cloud']
    del stuff['ai']
    del stuff['application']
    del stuff['client']
    del stuff['id']
    del stuff['type']
    del stuff['customMeasurements']
    del stuff['user']['authenticatedId']
    del stuff['user']['accountId']
    del stuff['request']['name']
    del stuff['request']['success']
    del stuff['request']['duration']
    del stuff['request']['performanceBucket']
    del stuff['request']['resultCode']
    del stuff['request']['source']
    del stuff['request']['id']


newstuff = json.dumps(data, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
#print(newstuff)
# Now it's in a cleaner format to work with
data2 = json.loads(newstuff)
json_normalize(data2['value'])
```

From here the data is in a pandas dataframe and looks like I want it to.
I just need to know how to use the furl to pull the limit and location out of the url on a per row basis and create a new column called load and limits as mentions above.

Comment: Don't forget that you have a typo in `user = x['user']['id]`. You forgot to put `'   '` around `id`

Comment: Thanks.  That's the easy part.  I'll fix it in the question

Comment: I've never used Pandas DataFrames, but you can check if the dictionary has a particular key using the `in` operator. For example, `limit = url.args['limit'] if 'limit' in url else None`.

Comment: Harry, I tried what you suggested but I'm getting  argument of type 'furl' is not iterable

Comment: Ah, my bad, what about checking `'limit' in url.args` instead? Otherwise, you can use the `get` method with a default value (`url.args.get('limit', default=None)`).